# Difference between subsequent columns in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In below dataframe, using pandas I would like to subtract values from subsequent years to get results like this:

input:

```
         2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
Michael   10   12   15   8    3
John      7    5    6    12   25  
Mitch     3    13   5    7    8
Jeff      1    0    11   6    9  
Ron       0    5    5    4    2
```

Output

```
        2000  2001 2002 2003 2004
Michael        2    3    -7    -5
John          -2    1     6    13  
Mitch          10   -8    2    1
```

Thank you for help

Comment: `df.diff(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. However, as @Quang Hoang put in the comments, it is much wasier to do with `df.diff(axis=1)`. It did not occur to me when I was putting this answer.

```
df.sub(df.shift(axis=1))
```

In this code, we are basically shifting all columns one step in axis=1 (vertically) and subtracting it with what is actually there. `df.diff(axis=1)` is in-built function for that.

**Output**

```
2000    2001    2002    2003    2004
Michael     NaN     2.0     3.0     -7.0    -5.0
John    NaN     -2.0    1.0     6.0     13.0
Mitch   NaN     10.0    -8.0    2.0     1.0
Jeff    NaN     -1.0    11.0    -5.0    3.0
Ron     NaN     5.0     0.0     -1.0    -2.0
```